# TFS Version Control: Check in .csproj with Subset of New Files

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Using *Visual Studio 2012* along with *TFS Version Control*, I often encounter the following scenario:

I'll add, say, **file A** and **file B** to my local project. Given the way Visual Studio works, these additions are reflected in my `.csproj` file as well.

Now, at times, I may be ready to check-in the newly-added **file A** but not **file B**.

Checking in **file A** but not the `.csproj` file to source control is not optimal because it excludes **file A** from the project. On the other hand, checking-in the `.csjproj` file puts the repository in an erroneous state since the project 'includes' **file B** but doesn't actually have the physical file.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

You can shelve your changes (preserve pending), delete file B, then check in what remains (file A add and the csproj update for A).

Then unshelve your shelveset.